# ASP.Net MVC:system componentmodel dataannotations value cannot be null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, data-annotations, vs-unit-testing-framework

when i am doing unit test my custom validation logic then i am getting this error

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in 
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll but was not handled in user
>   code
>
> Additional information: Value cannot be null.

here is my full code. so please see and tell me where i made the mistake ?

### My Model code

```
public class DateValTest
{
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [MyDate(ErrorMessage = "Back date entry not allowed")]
    [DateGreaterThanAttribute(otherPropertyName = "StartDate", ErrorMessage = "End date must be greater than start date")]
    public DateTime?  EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

### here is my custom validation code

```
public class MyDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public DateTime _MinDate;

    public MyDateAttribute()
    {
        _MinDate = DateTime.Today;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        DateTime _EndDat = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime _CurDate = DateTime.Today;

        int cmp = _EndDat.CompareTo(_CurDate);
        if (cmp > 0)
        {
            // date1 is greater means date1 is comes after date2
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else if (cmp < 0)
        {
            // date2 is greater means date1 is comes after date1
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            // date1 is same as date2
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "restrictbackdates",
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("mindate", _MinDate);
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

### my unit test code which is throwing error

```
[TestClass]
    public class MyDateAttribute_Test
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ValidationException))]
        public void Test_EndDateIsInvalidIFBackDate()
        {
            var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
            DateValTest model = new DateValTest() { EndDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10) };
            ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(model);
            Validator.TryValidateProperty(model, context, validationResults);
            Assert.IsTrue(validationResults.Count > 0);
        }
    }
```

highlight the area where i made the mistake. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solve it this way.

```
[TestMethod]
//[ExpectedException(typeof(ValidationException))]
public void Test_EndDateIsInvalidIFBackDate()
{
    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
    DateValTest model = new DateValTest() { StartDate = DateTime.Today, EndDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10) };
    ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(model);
    MyDateAttribute attribute = new MyDateAttribute();
    //attribute.Validate(model.EndDate, context);
    Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, validationResults, true);
    //Assert.IsFalse(validationResults.Count > 0);
    Assert.AreEqual(false, (validationResults.Count > 0), "Test Equalateral");
    //Assert.IsTrue(validationResults.Any(vr => vr.ErrorMessage == "Back date entry not allowed"));
}
```